# how to get rid of the module.class when importing module from package

Tags: python, class, module, package

So i have that python app that uses a package MyPackage,
in the **init**.py file of my package i have (among others) :

```
from Mesure import Mesure`
```

where Mesure.py is a module containing a class Mesure

to import that class i can write :

```
from Mypackage import Mesure
```

or :

`import Mypackage.Mesure as Mesure`

etc...
but then to instanciate the class i can't do :

```
m = Mesure() # gives a "module object is not callable " error`
```

i need to do

```
m = Mesure.Mesure() # good, no errors
```

this is redundant and i would like to find a way to write Mesure and get the class (not the module)
i tried :

```
import MyPackage.Mesure as mes
import mes.Mesure # gives a "no module named mes " error
```

i also tried to delete the line in the **init**.py file but this does not change anything

So the question is : Do i need to write Mesure.Mesure every time i want to instanciate the class ?
thank you in advance.

Comment: The file that's named `Mesure` should probably be named `mesure`. I think you're just re-importing the file, instead of importing the class. Having the names be different (even by just one capital) will make this easier to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you import `Mesure` module but use it like a Class, it should be

```
from Mypackage.Mesure import Mesure
```

or

```
import Mypackage.Mesure.Mesure
```

python module name is lowercase normally.